# Error while testing in karma : AppComponent should render title in a h1 tag

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am new to `Angular`. I am learning angular from https://angular.io/guide/quickstart.

I have to create my first `Angular` application as mentioned in the angular quick start page. It's works fine but when I am testing in `Karma` it gives me the below error. I try to change what is mention in the error but it gives me the same error.

> Error: Expected 'app' to contain 'Welcome to my-app!'.
>   at stack (http://localhost:9876/absoluteC:/Users/Project/my-app/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?0b1eaf7a13cae32191eadea482cfc96ae41fc22b:2455:17)
>   at buildExpectationResult (http://localhost:9876/absoluteC:/Users/Project/my-app/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?0b1eaf7a13cae32191eadea482cfc96ae41fc22b:2425:14)
>   at Spec.expectationResultFactory (http://localhost:9876/absoluteC:/Users/Project/my-app/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?0b1eaf7a13cae32191eadea482cfc96ae41fc22b:901:18)
>   at Spec.addExpectationResult (http://localhost:9876/absoluteC:/Users/Project/my-app/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?0b1eaf7a13cae32191eadea482cfc96ae41fc22b:524:34)
>   at Expectation.addExpectationResult (http://localhost:9876/absoluteC:/Users/Project/my-app/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?0b1eaf7a13cae32191eadea482cfc96ae41fc22b:845:21)
>   at Expectation.toContain (http://localhost:9876/absoluteC:/Users/Project/my-app/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?0b1eaf7a13cae32191eadea482cfc96ae41fc22b:2369:12)

Comment: Know issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11003. Just fix the test, or the code. If you tried and it ddn't work, then you did it wrong, but since you didn't post the code nor the test, we can't tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: Thanks, Fateh for the answers. The link u shared is useful.